# Access ~/.ssh/id_rsa from gitlab runner using docker+machine

Tags: docker, gitlab, gitlab-ci-runner

I'm fairly new to Docker so I might be missing something.
I have a ec2 instance with gitlab-runner on it that spawns ec2 instances to be used as Gitlab runners.
Here's my Dockerfile

```
# syntax=docker/dockerfile:1

FROM python:3.9

RUN apt-get -y install openssh-client

RUN ssh-keygen -q -t rsa -N '' -f /root/.ssh/id_rsa
```

I built, tagged and pushed the image to AWS ECR. The image is then used on the runners when a gitlab job is created. But for the life of me I just cant figure out why the files on ~/.ssh/ cant be accessed on the runner. I've tested access to those files on the CLI of Docker Desktop and had no trouble accessing those files.

Here is the .gitlab-ci.yml

```
before_script:
   - chmod 700 ~/.ssh
   - chmod 600 ~/.ssh/id_rsa
   - chmod 644 ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub
```

The error on the runner is:

```
chmod: cannot access '/root/.ssh/id_rsa': No such file or directory
```

Answer (score 0):

Either the image is not properly configured in your `runners.docker` section.

```
  [runners.docker]
    image = "alpine" <=== your ECR image?
```

Or EC2 mount a `/root/.ssh` folder which obscure the initial content of that image.